# MPAndroidChart removing data set issue

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have implemented to simple methods:

```
@Override
protected void addDataSet(int day) {
    LineData lineData = this.lineChart.getData();

    if(lineData != null) {
        ArrayList<Entry> yValues = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        for(int i = 0; i < this.measureDataListEntries.size(); i++) {
            String stringValue = this.measureDataListEntries.get(i).getValue();
            int dayOfWeek = Helper.getDayOfWeek(this.measureDataListEntries.get(i).getTime());
            float value = Float.parseFloat(stringValue);

            if(dayOfWeek == day) {
                yValues.add(new Entry(value, i));
            }
        }

        String label = this.getLabel(day);
        int color = this.getColor(day);

        LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(yValues, label);
        lineDataSet.setColor(color);
        lineDataSet.setCircleColor(color);
        lineDataSet.setLineWidth(1f);
        lineDataSet.setCircleSize(4f);
        lineDataSet.setFillAlpha(65);

        lineData.addDataSet(lineDataSet);

        this.lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.lineChart.invalidate(); 
        this.lineChart.animateX(1000);

        if(yValues.size() > 0) {
            this.getCheckBox(day).setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void removeDataSet(int day) {
    LineData lineData = this.lineChart.getData();

    if(lineData != null) {
        String label = this.getLabel(day);

        lineData.removeDataSet(lineData.getDataSetByLabel(label, true));

        this.lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.lineChart.invalidate(); 
        this.lineChart.animateX(1000);
    }
}
```

At startup i add seven different datasets: monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday. The adding and removing of datasets works for all days except the day at the first position of the dataset in this case it is monday. the remove method gets called correctly but the dataset does not get removed. adding works always.

**Only the dataset at first position cant be removed**

Is there a workaround?

**EDIT**

The code used for the deletion from `MPAndroidChart` is the following:

```
public T getDataSetByLabel(String label, boolean ignorecase) {

    int index = getDataSetIndexByLabel(mDataSets, label, ignorecase);

    if (index <= 0 || index >= mDataSets.size())
        return null;
    else
        return mDataSets.get(index);
}
```

why there is `<= 0` and not just `< 0`?

Ofcourse adding a dummy dataset at the first position would make it working but im never a friend of such ugly codings. Why dont accept index = 0 for deliting?

Answer (score 1):

This is already fixed. **Use the latest version** of the library.

Refer this: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/255

**Fixed since 16th December, 2014.**

Comment: The latest release i found is 1-7-4 (https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases/tag/v1.7.4) the bug is not fixed in this release.